# looking for some ASP session management tutorials

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, session

I need some tutorials or samples which cover the following topics, does anyone have any recommendations?

1. For ASP.Net, how to manage session and especially manage correctly when there is large number of concurrent user requests, access session and various ways to manage session expire;
2. For old ASP, how to manage session and especially manage correctly when there is large number of concurrent user requests, access session and various ways to manage session expire.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ASP.NET**

[ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) is a white paper by Rob Howard over on MSDN which goes into length discussing the ASP.NET Session object and it's uses.

More from MSDN:

- [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)
- [Quick Starts with ASP.NET Session State](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/applications/default.aspx)

Other Sources:

- [Exploring ASP.NET Session State and Cache Data (Code Project)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/exploresessionandcache.aspx)
- [Managing Session State For ASP.NET (InformIT)](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30026)

---

**Classic ASP**

W3Schools has some great ASP tutorials including the [ASP Session Object](http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/asp_sessions.asp) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET has great tutorials, here is one that covers [session management](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/applications/default.aspx).

Comment: Seems not having a one stop printable page?

Comment: If you want to print the source, you can click on the view source buttons and print from those pages.